# Retrieve value of jQuery array element when clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use the var "next" to get the id stored in array "images" based on the index of the clicked div. I need to do it this way because the div id can be anything as it is php based.

**JavaScript**

```
var currentImage = 1;
var numImages = 0;
var images = new Array();

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.gallerypreview').each(function(i) {
        images.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });

    $('.gallerypreview').click(function() {
        var current = $(this).index();
        alert(current);
    });

    $('.gallerypreview').each(function() {
        numImages++;
    });

    $('.galleryrightbtn').click(function() {
        moveLeft();
        current++;
        var next = $(current).get(this);
        $('.gallerylightbox').hide(300);
        $(next).show(300);
    });

    $('.galleryleftbtn').click(function() {
        moveRight();
        current--;
        var next = $(current).get(this);
        $('.gallerylightbox').hide(300);
        $(next).show(300);
    });

});

function moveLeft() {

    if ((currentImage + 1) == numImages) {
        $('.galleryrightbtn').css('display', 'none');
        $('.galleryleftbtn').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('.galleryrightbtn').css('display', 'block');
        $('.galleryleftbtn').css('display', 'block');
    }
    if (currentImage < numImages) {

        currentImage++;
    }
}

function moveRight() {

    if ((currentImage - 1) == 1) {
        $('.galleryleftbtn').css('display', 'none');
        $('.galleryrightbtn').css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $('.galleryleftbtn').css('display', 'block');
        $('.galleryrightbtn').css('display', 'block');
    }

    if (currentImage <= numImages) {
        currentImage--;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallerypreview" id="<?php echo $idvalue; ?>"></div>
<div class="gallerypreview" id="<?php echo $idvalueagain; ?>"></div>
<div class="gallerypreview" id="<?php echo $idvaluewhoknows; ?>"></div>
```

I am wondering if .get is the proper jQuery handler to be using.

Comment: `$.get()` is a wrapper for an AJAX request with the GET HTTP method.

Comment: You don't need an array at all to accomplish this, and if you make a working fiddle you will receive help much more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

As people mentioned in the comments, `$.get()` is a wrapper for an AJAX request with the GET HTTP method and maybe you don't need an array to acomplhish what you want.

But, assuming that you just want to get the value stored in your images array, you could just use:

`var next = images[current];`

**Or**

You could use the `.eq()` filter to get the element you want at a given index without having to store everything in an array, try this in your code:

`$('.gallerypreview').click(function() {
        // You could just use $(this).attr('id'); to get the id of the clicked div
        // the code below is for the sake of example
        var current = $(this).index();
        var galleryPreviewId = $( '.gallerypreview' ).eq( current ).attr( 'id' );
        alert( "The id of the div is: " + galleryPreviewId );
    });`

The `$( '.gallerypreview' ).eq( index )` reduces the matched set of elements (all elements with class gallerypreview) to the one at the specified index.

Note: After getting the id of the element, you may need to use the prefix `#` in order to show the DOM element whose id is equals to "next": `$( '#' + next ).show()`

See [.eq() filter](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) for more reference.